# Only keep the best trial using keras-tuner (Hyperband)

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, keras-tuner

How can I tell `keras_tuner` to only save the best model (overwriting each trial) and not create any checkpoints or directories for each trial?

There has been discussion already about how to reduce the amount of disk space that `keras_tuner` uses by either [re-implementing](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner/issues/288#issuecomment-1423600748) `run_trial()` or [adjusting](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner/issues/288#issuecomment-1685167496) the `_save_trail()` in `HyperbandOracle` (which I'm not using). These processes both attempt to implement what I desire and I tried it below

```
import keras_tuner as kt

### Make Hyperband Class update
class HyperbandTuner(kt.Hyperband):
    def __init__(self, hypermodel, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(hypermodel, **kwargs)

    def run_trial(self, trial, *args, **kwargs):
        hp = trial.hyperparameters
        model = self.hypermodel.build(hp)
        return self.hypermodel.fit(hp, model, *args, **kwargs)
```

but `trial_XXXX` folders were still created. Another option I tried was passing a checkpoint to `tuner.search()` like

```
best_model_checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
                            f'../Results/{directory}/{project_name}/best_model.hdf5',
                            save_best_only=True,
                            monitor='val_loss',
                            mode='min'
                       )
```

which saves the model after each trial if it's better than the previous model, but the issue with `trial_XXXX` directories persists.

I can also delete all the trial folders **after** the models finish running like

```
import shutil

### Remove all trials ###
trial_path = Path(f"{directory}/{project_name}")
shutil.rmtree(trial_path)
```

but it would be best to delete them as they're made or not make them at all. How can I do this?